# EXR compositing in Photoshop

Tags: compositing-nodes, color-management, .exr

Can anyone please explain to me what the proper steps are to get the same colors as from Blender's rendered result? I'm using AgX, but even with Filmic and Aces, it's a nightmare trying to figure out how to work the OCIO plugin for Photoshop to get the correct results. :'(

EDIT: Why did you close my question? The "duplicates" barely answer what I'm asking and none of them cover the question about the OCIO plugin for Photoshop. Also, the answers are from 2017. I'd appreciate a more recent discussion about this.